# Excel Strange Extra Digit

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In Excel 2007/2010, I get this strange behaviour:

```
Formula in cell: =2.6+1.4+4.62-8.2
Result in cell: 0.420000000000002000
```

Weird extra '2' about 14DP in. Can anyone explain why this is happening please?

Comment: This is likely the result of floating point calculations.  (Computers to not usually calculate in the decimal system. Instead they use binary, often about 80 bits deep binary. That is usually close enough but it is not precise and it leads to rounding errors).

Comment: This is indeed due to the decmial calculations and is not a bug.

Comment: Here is a decent MS KB on the topic: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214118

Comment: Probably because computer floating point math is in reality inexact, and gets worse the further out you go in decimal places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is *not* a bug. It is due to the inevitable inaccuracy of floating point arithmetic due to the finite number of bits available to store values, resulting in an approximate representation which becomes apparent the more significant digits you choose to display.

Here are some useful articles for you:

- [IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)
- [Numeric precision in Microsoft Excel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel)
- [Coding Horror - Why Do Computers Suck at Math?](http://blog.codinghorror.com/why-do-computers-suck-at-math/)
- [How to correct rounding errors in floating-point arithmetic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214118)
- [Floating-point arithmetic may give inaccurate results in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113)
- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)
- [Understanding Floating Point Precision, aka “Why does Excel Give Me Seemingly Wrong Answers?”](http://blogs.office.com/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/) ([Archived version with images](http://web.archive.org/web/20140312021725/http://blogs.office.com/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/))