# Subtract Excel not equaling 0

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I have a formula that is based on things being 0 based off a formula that subtracts the total. So essentially it is A1=10 and B1=4 and B2=6. My formula is imsub(a1,b1+b2) or =A1-sum(b1,b2). The problem is that sometimes excel minuses the numbers to equal a really really tiny number like  that is approximate to 0 thus messing up my other formula that is based off finding 0 to determine the IF function. How do I change it so it equals 0 and not a really small digit number?

I've taken a screenshot of what shows up
[image: ![link to my screen here]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your example does equal `0`. So, I cannot duplicate the problem we see Can you give us a better example? Is there a specific reason you are using `IMSUB`? Is there something else going on that you have not explained?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel Strange Extra Digit](https://superuser.com/questions/916296/excel-strange-extra-digit)

Comment: @CharlieRB I included a screenshot. It should equal 0, but it comes out to 2.xxxxx

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of [Excel Strange Extra Digit](https://superuser.com/questions/916296/excel-strange-extra-digit). The other question is "why this is happening?", this one is "how to deal with it?".

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I think that if you understand why it is happening, you will know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the `ROUND()` function, eg:

```
=ROUND(A1-SUM(B1,B2),4)
```

This rounds the value to four decimal places: choose the number of places you need to maintain the precision you need, but eliminate the small errors.

The errors occur when subtracting large numbers with a small difference, because of the limited precision of floating-point (non-integer) number storage.

Comment: this seemed to work and is what I was looking for thank you.